# What happened to the Yorkie in Old?

Tags: old-2021

The premise of the movie *Old* was that

> the beach accelerated processes in living cells.

However, there was a suggestion that animals are also affected because Trent noticed the remote beach had no fish, while at the resort’s main beach there were fish swimming around Trent and Idib’s feet when the friends were playing in the water. Also, one dead fish was shown washed up on the beach:

[image: A dead fish on the aging beach]

When the guests arrived to the hidden beach however, a small dog was with them. This dog should have been the first to show effects.

But what ever happened to Agnes’ little yorkshire terrier?

[image: Agnes brought her yorkie to the beach]

Answer (score 2):

[He dies](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2021/07/07/m-night-shyamalans-old-is-twisted-fun-with-a-twist-of-course).

> This leads to panic and distrust—but before the film can turn into a full whodunnit (or whendunnit), the old lady dies, too. Was she overwhelmed by the shock of the grisly floating corpse? Before we can get into that, oh weird, now the dog is dead, too. And all the kids feel funny. In fact, Maddox, who was 11 just a minute ago, has now transformed into 20-year-old Thomasin McKenzie. Luckily, Mom has a second bathing suit to lend her daughter.

According to [the entry on DoesTheDogDie.com](https://www.doesthedogdie.com/media/386897), there's no on-scene depiction of his death. It's just mentioned in conversation. From [a transcript](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/old-2021-transcript/):

> Something’s happening to her that’s triggering her hormones.
>
> The dog has died!
>
> Oh, my God.
>
> Oh, my God.
>
> He was only just alive.